# How do I sort database data in mongodb javascript? ( node.js )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, discord.js

I was creating bot in Discord.js. It has level system ( which you gain by writing things in the chat ) and I wanted to make a leaderboard, but I have to somehow sort the database out to do that, for example this is how it looks like now ( this is an example )

```
userId:"347707015956791297"
level:3
xp:231

userId:"267229922693611520"
level:1
xp:36

userId:"124575187579568129"
level:1
xp:81

userId:"466944003674472482"
level:4
xp:468
```

How do I make it look like this ( and if the person has same level, then it sorts it through xp ):

```
userId:"347707015956791297"
level:4
xp:468

userId:"267229922693611520"
level:3
xp:231

userId:"124575187579568129"
level:1
xp:81


userId:"466944003674472482"
level:1
xp:36
```

Comment: mongodb documentation covers how to sort https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

Comment: you have to sort in descending order i.e. `model.find().sort({level: -1})`

Answer (score 0):

To sort by two fields just call `sort` after `find` and indicate necessary fields and ascending/descending order:

```
db.users.find({ }).sort( { level: -1, xp: -1 } )
```

Comment: For some reason if I use this, this error appears:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Comment: That means `db.users` is undefined

Comment: You should indicate your model name instead of `users`